# Check if file exists [SH]

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement, sh

I created a script that will check for the existence of .gz files in the base directory and if it finds them it moved them into a new structure based on the current date. The script works perfectly when the shell is set to /bin/bash and I run it manually, but this script is run as a cron job (by logrotate) and I believe that it MUST be run under /bin/sh as I am not sure how to get logrotate to run it under /bin/bash. The code in question is

```
# Move rotated logs to the archive
if [ -f $BASEDIR/*.gz ]; then
        logger "$SNAME Moving rotated logs to $DIRECTORY"
        mv $BASEDIR/*.gz $DIRECTORY
else
        echo "$BASEDIR/*.gz"
        logger "$SNAME No rotated logs to move. Is this normal?"
fi
```

In bash the conditional check works great, under sh it complains there are too many arguments. If I put things in quotes it doesn't see the wildcard and aways returns false.

Any help would be fantastic!

Comment: As an aside -- all-caps names are used for variables with meaning to the OS or shell, whereas lowercase names are reserved for application use. See fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thank you for that information, I never knew that distinction and have always used all caps for globally available variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `[ -f pathname ]` takes *exactly one* name (`[ -f one.gz two.gz ]` isn't [valid `test` syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html)), but you don't know how many names `*.gz` expands to.

```
check() {
  set -- "$BASEDIR"/*.gz
  if [ -f "$1" ] || [ -L "$1" ]; then
    logger "$SNAME Moving rotated logs to $DIRECTORY"
    mv -- "$@" "$DIRECTORY"
  else
    echo "$BASEDIR/*.gz"
    logger "$SNAME No rotated logs to move. Is this normal?"
  fi
}
check
```

---

Breaking this down:

- `check() { ... }` defines a function named `check`, which we then call later.
- `set -- "$BASEDIR"/*.gz` replaces the function's argument list (this is why we're using a function, so we don't overwrite the whole script's argument list!) with a list of files with names ending in `*.gz`.
- `[ -f "$1" ]` tests if the *first* name in this list exists -- if it does, then we know that the expansion was successful. `[ -L "$1" ]` can also be true if the glob successfully expanded but the first entry was a symlink to a file that doesn't exist; by including it, we cover that corner case.
- `mv -- "$@" "$DIRECTORY"` reuses that argument list to pass to `mv`. The `--` argument specifies to `mv` that all following arguments are names, even if they start with `-`s.

Comment: Thank you a TON. This did the trick and everything works great!  I find it interesting that the single file limit was not a problem in bash but in sh it was an issue.

Comment: It *is* a problem in bash too -- I'm wondering if maybe you just didn't have more than one file ready to be transferred when testing earlier?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
if ls "$BASEDIR"/*.gz
then
    echo "moving them ..."
else
    echo "No such file!"
fi
```

Comment: `if ls "$BASEDRI"/*.gz &> /dev/null`...

Comment: My original answer also contained the suppressing of the output, but then I removed it because of clarity and because I had the feeling that OP might want to have this output, actually.  In the else case there already was such a message, and I considered it also useful in the then case.  But of course the suppression you proposed is standard in most such cases.